# Using an Oracle Data Reader with a ref cursor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oracle

I am trying to use an Oracle Data Reader with a ref cursor within a package I have created.

Using Visual Studio and C#.

Although I am getting two build errors concerning my reader:

1. .Parameters cannot be used like a method
2. MyReader is a variable but is used like a method.

Below is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=*****)(PORT=***))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=***)));User Id=APPS;Password=****;";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);  // C#
            conn.Open();


            OracleCommand myCMD = new OracleCommand();
            myCMD.Connection = conn;
            myCMD.CommandText = "apps.cie_install_base_data.get_serial_trx_hist";
            myCMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCMD.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            myCMD.Parameters.Add("p_serial_number", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 30).Value = "M5605946";
            OracleDataReader myReader = default(OracleDataReader);
            try
            {
                myCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception myex)
            {
                Label1.Text = " " + myex.Message;
            }

            myReader = myCMD.Parameters("p_cursor"); 

            int x = 0;
            int count = 0;

            count = 0;

            //myReader = myCMD.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read()) {
            for (x = 0; x <= myReader.FieldCount - 1; x++) {
            Label3.Text = myReader(x) + " ";
            }
            Label4.Text = " ";
            count += 1;
            }


            Label5.Text = (count + " Rows Returned.");

            myReader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
 }
```

If anyone can see why I am getting these build errors, or knows how I can get the data to be displayed properly that would be great.

Answer (score 5):

```
myReader = ((OracleRefCursor)myCMD.Parameters["p_cursor"].Value)).GetDataReader();
```

from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleRefCursorClass.htm

Answer (score 1):

Unlike VB, C# uses brackets to index collections.

Use `[]`, not `()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[]` instead of `()`.

From [`Arrays Tutorial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> When declaring an array, **the square brackets ([]) must come after
>   the type**, not the identifier. Placing the brackets after the
>   identifier is not legal syntax in C#.

Also [`OracleCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property returns [`OracleParameterCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparametercollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) not [`OracleDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, do you know how I could get the data to be displayed? And how I can rectify the problem with the line: `myReader = myCMD.Parameters("p_cursor"); `

Comment: @user2674605 Take a look at [SqlDataReader Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN. There a lot of methods that returns values from specific column and their types..

Answer (score -2):

You have to use ExecuteReader()...

```
//(Your code...)
  OracleDataReader myReader = default(OracleDataReader);
  try
  {   //Here the magic
      myReader = myCMD.ExecuteReader();
  }
  catch (Exception myex)
  {
      Label1.Text = " " + myex.Message;
  }

 int x = 0;
 int count = 0;

 string actualValue = string.Empty;
 /*This data type is from .Net. Like: "System.DateTime" - "System.String" - etc*/
 string actualDataType = string.Empty; 

 while(myReader.Read())
 {
  //Here you can use GetValue and GetType
     actualValue = myReader.GetValue(count).ToString();
     actualDataType = myReader.GetType(count).ToString();
     count++;
 }
```

Comment: This is not how you read from a refCursor.